# How to map json columns to String fields when generating Java objects

Tags: jooq, jooq-codegen

When Jooq generates Java objects, the json columns are mapped to org.jooq.JSON fields by default.

```sql
`keywords` json DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'keywords',
```

```java
private JSON keywords;
```

I want to map json columns to java.lang.String fields. How should I set up the xml configuration file?

Thanks.

The database I am using is MYSQL8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [data type rewriting in the code generator](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-advanced/codegen-config-database/codegen-database-forced-types/codegen-database-forced-types-rewrite/), pretending those are `VARCHAR` columns. E.g.

```xml
<forcedType>
  <name>VARCHAR</name>
  <includeExpression>(?i:keywords)</includeExpression>
</forcedType>
```

Or even:

```xml
<forcedType>
  <name>VARCHAR</name>
  <includeTypes>(?i:json)</includeTypes>
</forcedType>
```

[See the manual for all configuration options](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-advanced/codegen-config-database/codegen-database-forced-types/codegen-database-forced-types-matching/)